# How to allow a user to use data in an Amazon EC2 instance while not allowing it to copy

Tags: windows-server-2012, amazon-web-services

I would like to upload a data onto an Amazon Ec2 instance. The file is a dataset in Stata format.

I want to have someone else to be able run the data in Stata via remote desktop connected to the server while not be able to copy the file to his local computer.

Is this possible?

Comment: If a user can read data, he would be able to copy it anyhow. Just think about it, if someone gives you a book, you can always copy it, right? You can take it to a photocopier, or copy it by hand.

Comment: Right. The remote computer can always take a picture of the data and copy it. But I would like to know if there is any strategy to prevent him from simply email the data to himself, etc.

Comment: You would have to put security restrictions in place for every way the user could copy data. Email, but also using remote file shares, dropbox, copy-paste from Remote Desktop, Printing to PDF to the local machine over RDP. This might not be very practical, and nearly impossible to make properly secure.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Would it be too difficult to restrict email, dropbox?

Comment: You need to be more precise. What kind of data? What kind of access? If you put a PDF file on a web server you can't prevent them copying it if they can see it. If you install remote desktop on the server that lets them log in they could view the PDF but not download it.

Comment: I re-editted the question. Please see above.